# link on usercontrol referenced multiple times in same pages

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have a usercontrol with dropdown and a link beside on the usercontrol which opens popup depending on the value of dropdown

I have a page where I have referenced usercontrol twice using different IDs. But my problem is when I click individual link on the page, since the link is on the usercontrol itself as well as the value of dropdown, the value of dropdown that I select `$find('<%=RadComboBox1.ClientID%>').get_value();` 
is same for both cases, or finds from the last element

it coz the ID of RadComboBox1 is not related to the page rather its related to usercontrol now, so it will have same ID and will get the same value for both popup link

How do I get the link working correctly??

**UserControl**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openPopUp() {
        var ddlValue = $find('<%=RadComboBox1.ClientID%>').get_value();

        if (ddlValue.length <= 0) {
            alert('Please Select a Vendor');
        }
        else {
            var jsURL = "/Open.aspx?id=" + ddlValue;
            return OpenPOPWindow(jsURL, 550, 1250, 340, 160);
        }
    }
</script>

<telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="RadComboBox1" Height="190px" OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="javascript:openPopUp();" >
<a runat="server" id="lnkPopUp" visible="false"  href="javascript:void(0);">View Data</a>
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: How do I get to have those link work properly??

Comment: Can you post the code, so we can get some idea. even rendered html is better

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it gets the same ID? Because it shouldn't.

Why don't you update it to

```
javascript:openPopUp(this);
```

or add from code-behind:

```
RadComboBox1.OnClientSelectedIndexChanged = "openPopUp('" + RadComboBox1.ClientID + "')";
```

This means that openPopUp will always have the correct reference to you current combo box (first example) or combo box id (second example).

LATER EDIT:

I've just made some tests.

First, I created a user control with the following code:

```
Options here: 
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlOptions">
    <asp:ListItem Text="option 1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="option 2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="option 3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList> 
<a href="javascript:linkit('<%=ddlOptions.ClientID%>')">Link here</a>
```

Then I created a page with:

```
    <uc1:test runat="server" ID="test1" /><br />
    <uc1:test runat="server" ID="test2" />

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function linkit(id)
        {
            alert(document.getElementById(id).value);
        }
    </script>
```

Where uc1:test is the control described earlier.

If I select different options on the dropdown list and click the link, I get the correct selected options (different for each link).

Isn't this the same problem you are having?

Comment: I did that, but since its on both the usercontrols finally it has the id same on the page when it executes

Comment: So 'this' is always same, coz its the same control calling the javascript for pop-ups

Comment: Do you mean when you display <%=RadComboBox1.ClientID%> and <%=RadComboBox2.ClientID%> you get the same id? Have you checked the HTML source and are you sure this is happening? Because it is not possible.

Comment: When I check it from html that is the aspx page the ID of controls in usercontrol changes but the link is not on the page, its on the usercontrol itself so that ID won't help coz there is nothing handled in the aspx page rather handled on usercontrol